# getting on duplicate key mysql to work

Tags: mysql, insert

i am having trouble getting this to work,

can any one spot the issue?

```
INSERT INTO `page_category_link` (page_id,cat_id) 
VALUES ('4','2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_id=VALUES('4') AND cat_id=VALUES('2') WHERE id=2
```

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `page_category_link`
(page_id,cat_id) VALUES ('4','2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_id='4', cat_id='2'
```

Comment: @Johan Why did you add "WHERE id = '2'" to my answer?  That is not necessary and questionable whether it would even work.

Comment: Because (A) I hastily misread the query above (B) I had a knock on the head and revered to noob status (3) I'm just escaped from the institution and my meds are wearing off (D) counting is hard (E) I'm trying to get the copy editor badge (F) I forgo...., what was the question again?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `VALUES(page_id)` AND `VALUES(cat_id)`. You're essentially telling MySQL to use the value that was assigned to the `page_id` and `cat_id` columns to update the table with.

```
INSERT INTO `page_category_link` (page_id,cat_id) VALUES ('4','2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_id = VALUES(page_id) AND cat_id=VALUES(cat_id)
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why I'm being downvoted? Is this not the correct answer?

Comment: I think your "AND" should be a comma, no?

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
INSERT INTO page_category_link (page_id, cat_id) VALUES ('4', '2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_id=page_id, cat_id=cat_id WHERE id=2
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what I did wrong here. I checked it against MySQL's documentation.